# NSXMLStoreType or NSSqliteStoreType

Tags: macos, cocoa, core-data, persistent-storage

I am just wondering if there are any advantages and disadvantages such as performance when choosing between NSXMLStoreType and NSSqliteStoreType for Core Data persistent type?

I searched around, and only found NSXMLStoreType is not supported in iOS.

Comment: http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreData/Articles/cdPersistentStores.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40002875-SW3

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not supported in OS X? That's news to me (and to the apps in which I used the type for development).

NSXMLStoreType is GREAT for development purposes because you can actually look into the persistent store with a text editor (XML == human-readable) while SQLite or Binary store types are not. SQLite, however, is fastest because it supports atomic updates (update individual records without writing the entire store back out for one little change). XMLStoreType, by contrast trades this speed for readability.

I use XML type for debugging but SQLite in deployed apps. Well, those in which I still use Core Data, that is. CD isn't a good fit for everything. In fact, it's a so-so or poor fit for many when a custom-designed system works just fine (especially where filtering or property setting speed is important).

Comment: Ah. Well ignore that part, then. :-)

Comment: I am curious what the other options, except core data? Are you using sqlite or other database directly?

Comment: There are plenty of third-party Objective-C wrappers around SQLite and other database types (including many types of "object databases" all the kids are using these days ;-)). Alternatively, use standard Cocoa classes and serialize them to files as a PLIST or write NSCoder implementations for custom objects so they can be serialized when written. "Custom file format" is not a dirty phrase. Example: Your own address book app could have a model consisting entirely of an NSArray of NSCoder-compliant Person objects. A simple call to [people writeTo...] will serialize it out to a file where asked.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Very helpful information for me, gonna read more about core data so next time I can choose the right tool.